# Prevent Complete HTML Regeneration When Changing Symbol in TradingView Widget with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm working on integrating the TradingView widget into my React application to display cryptocurrency price charts. The widget initialization and symbol change are working as expected, but I've noticed that each time the symbol changes, the entire HTML for the widget seems to be regenerated, causing a potential performance impact.

Here's a simplified version of my TradingViewWrapper component:

`

```
 const TradingViewWrapper = React.memo(({ symbol }) => {
 console.log("symbol", symbol);
 const tvWidgetRef = useRef(null);
 useEffect(() => {
 var theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");

if (!tvWidgetRef.current) {
  tvWidgetRef.current = window.tvWidget = new window.TradingView.widget({
    fullscreen: false,
    symbol: symbol,
    interval: "1D",
    container: "tv_chart_container",
    height: 400,
    width: "100%",

    datafeed: new window.Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed(baseUrl + "/api"),
    library_path: "/charting_library/",
    locale: "en",

    disabled_features: ["use_localstorage_for_settings"],
    enabled_features: ["study_templates"],
    charts_storage_url: "https://saveload.tradingview.com",
    charts_storage_api_version: "1.1",
    client_id: "tradingview.com",
    user_id: "public_user_id",
    theme: theme !== "true" ? "light" : "dark",
    overrides: {
      "mainSeriesProperties.style": 8,
    },
    drawings_access: {
      type: "black",
      tools: [
        {
          name: "Brush",
        },
        {
          name: "Rectangle",
        },
      ],
    },
  });
} else {
  console.log(
    "tvWidgetRef",
    tvWidgetRef.current,
    tvWidgetRef.current.symbol
  );
  tvWidgetRef.current.symbol = symbol;

  // Refresh the chart to reflect the updated symbol
  // tvWidgetRef.current.chart().executeActionById("show-symbol-info");

}

// return () => {
//   widget && widget.remove();
// };
}, [symbol]);

return <div id="tv_chart_container"></div>;
});`
```

I'd like to optimize this behavior to prevent the complete regeneration of the HTML content of the TradingView widget each time the symbol prop changes. Instead, I want to find a way to only update the necessary parts of the widget's content without affecting the entire HTML structure.

Is there a way to achieve this while still keeping the TradingView widget up to date with the new symbol?